# WordPress - JS Cookies set but not sidewide available

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, cookies

I am working on a cookie wall for a network (multisite) of website.
My approach is:

- Register a custom post type "cookie_consent";
- then, create a corresponding custom template file "cookie-consent.php"
- In this custom template file, in the header is set a cookie function
- this function is activated (aka the cookie
  is set) after click on button
- then, by using isset() we investigate wether te
  cookie is set.
- If not set, redirect to the custom post type. If set,
  redirect home.

However, on all other pages i get the return that the cookie is not set, although I can see in my inspector that the cookie is set.

The code so far in the plugin:

```
function redirect(){
    $url = get_permalink(get_page_by_title( 'Cookie Wall', '', 'cookie_consent' ));
if (!isset($_COOKIE[clickagree]) && (! is_singular( 'cookie_consent' ) ) ) {
  wp_redirect ( $url );
  exit;
}
else{
          wp_redirect ( home_url() );
  exit;
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect' );

global $wp_version;

function create_post_type() {
    if ( ! current_user_can('editor')) {
  register_post_type( 'cookie_consent',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'cookie_consent' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'cookie_consent' )
      ),
      'capabilities' => array(
    'edit_post'          => 'update_core',
    'read_post'          => 'update_core',
    'delete_post'        => '',
    'edit_posts'         => 'update_core',
    'edit_others_posts'  => '',
    'delete_posts'       => '',
    'publish_posts'      => '',
    'read_private_posts' => '',
    'create_posts'       => '',
),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => false,
      'supports' => array(
                'editor',
                'custom-fields',
                'page-attributes',
                'thumbnail',
                'excerpt',
            ),
    )
  );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

define( 'cookie_consent_file', __FILE__ );

register_activation_hook( cookie_consent_file, 'cookie_consent_plugin_activation' );

function cookie_consent_plugin_activation() {
  if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) return;

  global $wpdb;
  if ( null === $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT post_name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_name = 'cookie-wall'", 'ARRAY_A' ) ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // create post object
    $post = array(
      'post_title'  => __( 'Cookie Wall' ),
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
      'post_type'   => 'cookie_consent',
    );
    // insert the post into the database

    wp_insert_post( $post );

  }

}

function agreebutton($atts, $content = null) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array($atts),$content));
   return '<button onClick="SetCookie( \'clickagree\',\'yes\')">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</button>';
}
add_shortcode('button', 'agreebutton');
```

In the template file i have the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: cookie template
 * Template Post Type: cookie_consent
 */
?>
<head>
<script>
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
 var today = new Date();
 var expire = new Date();
var nDays=365
 expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
                 + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}
</script>
<head/>
<body>
<style><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></style>
<div class="wrap" style="background: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');height:100%;overflow:auto">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <?php
                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                the_content();

                endwhile; // End of the loop.
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
```

I dont understand why the plugin doesn't recognise the cookie set on other pages/posts then the cookie_consent?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I found out that by setting a cookie, if you dont set the path /, it is only accessible on the page it was set. So the correct way to set the cookie is to add  + "; path=/"; at the end.

So the correct code looks like this:

```
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
var today = new Date();
var expire = new Date();
var nDays=365
expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
+ ";expires="+expire.toGMTString() + "; path=/"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

from w3 school